# Добавил фабрику, не могу найти $scope в контроллере

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

Я скоро начну есть свой пиджак, но домой не поеду, пока не найду причину. Начал как обычно с контроллера, потом второй. Добавил ngRoute, потребовалось написать factory и началось.
Контроллер FormsListCtrl отрабатывает как положено, список из базы доставляется и выводится на страницу, при этом в консоль попадает undefined.
А вот с контроллером EditorCtrl чудеса происходят. Фабрика должна вернуть, из ранее полученного списка форм, форму по указанному айди. Вроде бы она отрабатывает и возвращает то, что и требовалось. Где это найти? В консоле вот такие вещи просматриваются, но вот в разметку ничего не попадает. Скажите пожалуйста, где искать?

Причем из фабрики лог выводится последним.
Почему первый контроллер выводит на страницу, а второй(написан по аналогии) нет?

P.S. В коде HTML прописано все как полагается.

АП: на страницу не попадает, потому что вместо объекта из бд приходит строка, а в консоли нет, потому что фабрика отрабатывает после.

[image: ангуляр консоль]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru" ng-app="formEditor">
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" />
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js?456"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/script.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </body>
</html>


var formEditor = angular.module('formEditor', ['ngRoute']);

formEditor.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.
    when('/',{
        template:'<span ng-repeat="form in forms"><a href="#/{{form.id}}">{{form.name}}</a> </span>',
        controller:'FormsListCtrl'
    }).
    when('/:formIdi',{
        template:'<span ng-bind="set.b.brdr.style"></span><span ng-bind="set.c"></span><span ng-bind="set.d"></span>',
        controller:'EditorCtrl'
    }).
    when('/:formId',{
        templateUrl:'/view/view_editor.html',
        controller:'EditorCtrl2'
    }).
    otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});
});

// получаем список форм
formEditor.factory('formsFctr', function($http){
    function getData(callback){
        $http({
            method:'GET',
            url:'/ajax/action.php?action=form&sub=list',
            cache:true
        }).success(callback);
    }
    return{
        list:getData,
        find: function(param, callback){
            getData(function(data){
                var form = data.filter(function(entry){
                    return entry.id === param;
                })[0];
                callback(form);
            });
        }
    };
});

formEditor.controller('FormsListCtrl', ['$scope', 'formsFctr', function($scope, formsFctr){
    formsFctr.list(function(forms){
        $scope.forms = forms;
    });
    console.log($scope.forms);
}]);

formEditor.controller('EditorCtrl', 
        ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'formsFctr', function($scope, $routeParams, formsFctr){

    formsFctr.find($routeParams.formIdi, function(form){
        $scope.set = form.json;
        console.log($scope.set);
    });
    $scope.set = {b:{brdr:{style:"solid"}},c:"cycle",d:$routeParams.formIdi};
    console.log($scope.set);
    console.log($scope);

    // обработка переключателя H/V
    $scope.reModes = function(){
        if($scope.set.modes.done === 'horizontal'){
            $scope.set.b.width = 372;
        }   
        if($scope.set.modes.done === 'vertical'){
            $scope.set.b.width = 180;
        }   
    };



}]);
```

Comment: ну так потому и не выводится ничего, что `$scope.set` - строка и у нее нет полей к которым вы обращаетесь в шаблоне